# Query returns different results depending on column list in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW FRM_STATAGGREGATE_VIEW AS
SELECT a.id aggregate_id, 
       SUM(S.PROD_TIME) PROD_TIME1, 
       SUM(S.PROD_TIME) PROD_TIME2
FROM wms_aggregate a
LEFT JOIN wms_stat_user s
ON a.id = s.aggregate_id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT prod_time1, NULL
FROM FRM_StatAggregate_VIEW
WHERE aggregate_id = 183
UNION ALL
SELECT prod_time1, prod_time2
FROM FRM_StatAggregate_VIEW
WHERE aggregate_id = 183;
```

The query produces the following results:

```
PROD_TIME1  PROD_TIME2
60  <NULL>
0   0
```

In other words, when I include both columns in query, they return value of 0, but when only one is included, the return value (60) is correct.

When I clone table used in view and recreate the view, the results are correct.

My question is: is this an Oracle bug? Or are these results possible due to any database/table/view configuration, indexes, etc.?

Comment: what does `select * from yourview` return?

Comment: What does the execution plan look like for the union-all'd query? Also, when you split that query into separate queries, do you see the same results (i.e. does selecting one column still produce 60, but both produces 0?). My guess is possibly there's some query rewriting going on with the query that's selecting both columns that's causing things to go awry.

Comment: Regardless of any "database/table/view configuration, indexes, etc." this looks like a bug; whatever the database is or is not doing behind the scenes, it should produce the correct result, otherwise it's a bug by definition. Unless the code is not exactly as you posted it (such things do happen on SO, and not rarely).

Comment: I've just knocked up the same test and I get two values of 60 when selecting both PROD_TIME values. I'm using 11g so if its a bug it doesn't manifest in that version. Incidentally, it seems strange to select the same column twice in a view.

Comment: Check the execution plan. There is at least on bug related to pushing down predicates from UNIONS into views. If you see an `UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE` in your plan you are likely affected by that. Check MyOracleSupport for details and fixes

Comment: @all select * produced "183,0,0" result. union here is just for presentation purposes - two separate selects with different column list produce different results. Anyways, when I recreated the tables, the results are correct. So 99.999% Oracle bug... thank you.

Comment: @BriteSponge. Can you share your testcase

Comment: @BobC - I'm happy to do that and have it ready but obviously it isn't an answer and is too long for a comment. Any suggestions how it could be shared ?

Comment: @BriteSponge. Want to send it to via email?

Comment: @bobc - I can do that. Email my username at gmail dot com and I'll send it on Monday.

Comment: @BriteSponge. Email on its way.

Comment: @amnezjak. Are you saying the problem has disappeared? Are you still able to reproduce it?

Comment: @BobC after recreating the table I'm not able to reproduce the problem :(